# How to pass multiple templates to flask.render_template()

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to deploy a flask app and I want a flask.render_template() method passed with a list of html files. Here I see it's eligible. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.render_template

I'm trying with this code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    templs = ["_header.html", "_footer.html"]
    return render_template(templs)

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But actually server returns only the first template from the list.
How to iterate though this list in order to render all templates from the list?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Why would you want to render multiple template? You can only return one to the client anyway. Have a look at the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.render_template): render_template only renders the first template in your list: *"template_name_or_list – the name of the template to be rendered, or an iterable with template names **the first one existing will be rendered**"*

Comment: I want to have a pair of static files like header.html and footer.html for all the web pages I'd have on my site. They have all the style sheets and scripts links I need. Actually I want dynamically concatenate(merge) header, footer and body .html files. Like in php you just sequentially load files and browser renders it as a single page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as i see you are trying to render static header and footer. I'd recommend to prepare something like "layout.html" with included header and footer:

```
//layout.html
<html>
    <head>//headhere</head>
    <header>//your static header</header>
    <main>
        {% block body %}
        //content will be here
        {% endblock %}
    </main>
    <footer> //your static footer </footer>
</html>
```

then in "child" templates(ex: index.html)use:

```
//index.html
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
   //your code here
{% endblock %}
```

It will render header and footer from layout.html and rest from index.html.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to render multiple templates. What you want is to render one template that combines multiple templates. That is the task of templating engine, not Flask. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/ (Flask uses Jinja).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like @jbasko wrote!
Making use of two `{{block}}` statements worked for me:
For example, I put in my **routes.py**

```
@app.route("/page1")
def page1():
       return render_template('page1.html', title='Title')
```

the **page1.html** is containing simply **two block-specifications**

```
{% extends "page1.html" %}
{% block content %}  
<h1> Content </h1>
{% endblock content %}

{% block info %}
<h1> Info </h1>
{% endblock info %}
```

which gets referenced in **layout.html** in two separate places:

```
 {% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

and later

```
 {% block info %}{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this...

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/')
def hello():
   render_header = render_template('_header.html')
   render_footer = render_template('_footer.html')
   return render_header + render_footer

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```