# HTML/CSS - Keep Variable Across Multiple Stylesheets

Tags: html, css-variables

So the basic way my website functions is that there is a "base.html" and "base.css" template which has a top bar and defines the variables of page color, text color, etc. respectively, like this:

```
:root {
--text-primary: #b6b6b6;
--text-secondary: #5f5f5f;
--bg-primary: #23232e;
--bg-secondary: #141418;
}
```

Then, the other HTML pages start with `{% extends "base.html" %}` and then insert their content into the body of the page. Each of these other pages will also import a stylesheet. For example, one page uses a table to show different options. I want that table to have the items in it colored to `var("--bg-primary")` but when I use a variable defined in the root of one stylesheet, I still can't use it in another even though the final page after extends will have both stylesheets imported. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what is the server side code you use?

Comment: @DickensAS Flask, but why does that matter?

Comment: if you wanted to split your files as header.html, footer.html, then you have few choice, you need to follow a client side framework or client template system, or you need to do it at server side template system, in flask you can use `render_template` add combine html files ... refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483315/how-to-pass-multiple-templates-to-flask-render-template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should not matter if the CSS custom properties are declared in an external CSS file or the same file. e.g.

global.css

```
:root {
--text-primary: #b6b6b6;
--text-secondary: #5f5f5f;
--bg-primary: #23232e;
--bg-secondary: #141418;
}
```

style.css

```
.primary {
    color: var(--text-primary);
}
.secondary {
    color: var(--text-secondary);
}
.bg-primary {
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
}
.bg-secondary {
    background-color: var(--bg-secondary);
}
```

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="global.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="primary">foo</div>
        <div class="secondary">bar</div>
        <div class="bg-primary">baz</div>
        <div class="bg-secondary">bat</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

result:

[image: result of the above code example]

So it has to be to do with either the order you are importing your css - or else something else to do with how your page is set-up.

So to answer you question: Is there a way to do this?
Yes - that is how they work out of the box.

As an aside you can also access/set your custom properties via javascript. e.g.

```
getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("--text-primary");
element.style.setProperty("--text-primary", "#f0f0f0");
```

Comment: Does the fact that due to the way block content works, I imported the first "base" stylesheet in the <main> tag but the second specific stylesheet in <body> batter?

Comment: even when I place both <link> tags in <main>, it still doesn't work...

Comment: @Theo I don't know what you mean by `<main>` and `<body>` tags - you don't have them in your question...if your question is "why is this code not working" then please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Theo - a `<link>` element can only occur either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element - so try adding your links to the head or body   - rather than in some random page element like `<main>`...

Comment: I see all the text as normal black on white.

Comment: @Theo - then there is something else to do with your setup - which browser are you using? That works 100% in chrome 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 74.0 (64-bit) on Windows 10 - the image I posted is a screen-grab of the page on chrome. So the problem is something to do with some information you are not providing. Again - this is how CSS custom properties work out of the box. See - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables - for compatibility.

Comment: @Theo - also 100% works on Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 on Windows 10

Comment: I got it to work, not sure how but I just changed my Flask server settings a bit and it works now. Either way, thanks!